# Sitecore Master DB version stored in which field or table

Tags: sitecore

Where in Sitecore Master Database is version related data stored?

Both Master and Web has the same schema. So curious how version is managed in Master DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web databases contain only one version of an item for a given language, optimize for speed. However there can be multiple version because testing functionality e.t.c. The Master database contain all versions.

When in comes to the database storage
an item contains Fields, VersionedFields, SharedFields and UnversionedFields
The VersionedFields are stored in a table VersionedFields with a column for Language and Version. On this way it is managed.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you create a new item, there is a new row added to the `dbo.Items` table in your `master` database.

There is always only one row for each item in that table. Even if you create a new version of the item.

When you create a new version, there are new rows added to the `dbo.VersionedFields` table. You can see row for fields like '__Revision`,`__Created by`. Every row in this table is uniquely identified by`[ItemId], [Language], [Version], [FieldId]` set.

If you check `dbo.`VersionedFields`in your`web`database, you will see only 1 version of the item per language. That means that when you publish a newer version of an item from`master`to`web`database, the older version is removed from the`web` database and only the new version is there.